# default settings parent to child in angular4

Tags: angular

Hi i am trying to get default settings data from parent component, But i am unaware of getting this can u please help.

```
 this.settings = {
'filter': {
            'quick': [{
                'name': 'status',
                'values': [{
                    'label': 'Active',
                    'value': 'Active'
                },
                    {
                        'label': 'Inactive',
                        'value': 'Inactive'
                    }
                ]

            }]
        }
}
```

in parent Html i am passing settings to smart table component

```
 <smart-table class="immiviewClientsTable"
                     [settings]="settings"
                     [data]="data"
                     [paginationData]="paginationData"
                     (onAddClick)="addNewCli($event)"
                     (onRowClick)="onUserRowClick($event)"
                     (dataWithQueryParams)="dataWithParameters($event)"></smart-table>
```

in smart table component i am stuck how to get that settings data to drop down.
like quick as heading and option values as Active and Inactive

Comment: have you declared settings as `@Input()` in `smart-table` component?

Comment: in your `smartTable` you have an `@Input`  called `settings` , use this variable , otherwise can yuo explain more you problem ?

Comment: @NadunLiyanage yes

Comment: @MohamedAliRACHID how to get data in html page

Comment: show your HTML code so i can see how to get data in html?

Comment: You can use `*ngFor` to go through the arrays. Is that your problem? still its not clear

Comment: <select [(ngModel)]="selected" (ngModelChange)="onSelect(selected)">
            <option *ngFor="let option of filter"
                    [value]="values">
                {{ values }}
            </option>
        </select>

Comment: @NadunLiyanage please help

Comment: @MohamedAliRACHID please help

Comment: Why this much of keys? can we format the JSON like this? 
`filter= 
      [{
        "name": "quick",
        "values": [{
          "label": "Active",
          "value": "Active"
        },
        {
          "label": "Inactive",
          "value": "Inactive"
        }
        ]

      }]`

Comment: then we can simply loop through the array and get the elements inside for a set of different dorp-downs

Comment: @NadunLiyanage i am not able to loop in dropdown

Comment: @NadunLiyanage can you show how to loop

Answer (score 0):

In order to loop and create multiple drop-down menus, you should have a set of variables to bind the selected values of each. Else you can have an attribute in the JSON object itself so that could be bound. (Assuming that you can change the JSON object as I suggested)

```
filters= [
{ 
  "name": "quick", 
  "values": [
             { 
               "label": "Active", 
               "value": "Active" 
             }, 
             { 
               "label": "Inactive", 
               "value": "Inactive" 
             } 
            ],
   "selection": "" 
}];
```

then in the template,

```
<div *ngFor="let filter of filters">
 {{filter.name}}
    <select [(ngModel)]="filter.selection" (ngModelChange)="onSelect($event)"> 
       <option *ngFor="let value of filter.values" [ngValue]="value.value"> 
        {{value.label}} 
       </option> 
    </select>
</div>
```